# toString Method to print out a game board with a 2D boolean array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, boolean, tostring

I am trying to write a toString method that will take a 2D boolean array and print out "x" or "_" depending on if they are true or false which has been randomly initialized. However, every time I go to print the board I return a memory address, and I don't think it ever goes to my toString which I am overriding the method correctly I believe. I have posted my code below along with an example of how I want the format to turn out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public static boolean[][] randomize() {

        //Initializes random
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++) {
                board[row][col] = random.nextBoolean();
            }
        }

        return board;
    }
 @Override
    public String toString() {
        String result = ""; 

        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(i);
            result += i;
        }
        result += "\n";
        System.out.println();

        for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
            System.out.print(row);
            result += row;
            for (int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++) {
                if (board[row][col] == false) {
                    System.out.print("_");
                    result += "_";
                }
                else if (board[row][col] == true) {
                    System.out.print("X");
                    result += "X";
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
            result += "\n";
        }

        return result;
    }  

public void play() {
        currentStatus = GameState.IN_PROGRESS;
        DuoPlayPlayer currentPlayer = playerOne;

        //Creates and Prints the Board
        boolean[][] board = LightsOut.randomize();
        System.out.println(board);
        System.out.println(currentPlayer.getName() + " it is your turn!");
}
```

Comment: @michalk you are right, `toString()` is called when passing an object to `System.out.println()`.

Answer (score 2):

Here

```
boolean[][] board = LightsOut.randomize();
System.out.println(board);
```

you are trying to print the board, but  board is actually a two dimensional array of primitive booleans. The `toString()` method that you have overriden will work for objects of a class which `toString()` method was overriden for. If you pass variables of array types to `System.out.println` method, it will print their address.

If you really want to print your boolean board consider using [Arrays.toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(boolean[])) method in a loop - as this method works for one dimensional arrays only. If you want to print 2d arrays with this method you will get arrays addresses for second dimension. Or consider using [Arrays.deepToString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString-java.lang.Object:A-) which does not require a loop. However this will print true/false values in your console.

In your case it would be advisable maybe to create a class called `Board` which would contain two dimensional array of booleans as member, and you could override `toString()` method for `Board` class. Then it would be possible for you to do something like :

```
    Board board = new Board();
    System.out.println(board);
```

And here the overriden `toString()` method of `Board` class could be called implicitly.

I have also noticed that the way you are creating the final result in this `toString()` method is not optimal. You should read about topics like String immutability, string pool and using classes like [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).